# Recycle view scrolling slow after return from a activity

Tags: android, video-streaming, video-processing

I have developed a app that has two section one for street food and other kitchen food vlogs it plays video from each section, but i the recycler view present in that code starts to scroll slow as the video is played and user returns back to the previous activity

Eventually whole app starts working slow as any of the video showed it played in recycler view

- the items are stored in firebase
- the video is streamed using url
- using video view
- by setting videoview.setimageuri
- eventually whole app slows down when
  The video is streamed or starts streaming
- app also consumes very much data while playing video
- video isn't compressed

Comment: upgrade your device

Comment: It does so in every higher version device as well

Comment: and firebase have some listner for data in firebase database and storage which makes the app slow. I didn't find any solution for that yet.

Comment: No i didn't find a solution